# options with collection.fetch()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to fetch multiple sets of same collection type at once. After the results are fetched, I would like to sort the results in the callback based on some "id", which I set on the collection before calling the fetch() method.

**The issue:** How do I pass the collection's id to the callback?

**The hack I'm using right now:** I have an array for storing the ids and one for the results. I push the id to the ids array before calling the fetch method and push into the results in the success callback.

**The problem with this:** Since the ids are pushed in a loop, all of them are in order. But the fetch happens async and whichever returns first gets pushed into the results array, thereby breaking the order.

**Sample Code:**

```
// Current Date
var curDate = new Date();

// List of categories and points
var categories = new Array();
var points = new Array();

// A Backbone Collection
var users = new app.UserList();

for(var i=0; i<=curDate.getMonth(); i++) {
    users.setMonthNumber(curDate.getMonth()-i);
    categories.unshift(parseInt(users.getMonthNumber()+1) + '/12');

    users.fetch({
        success: function(collection, response){
            points.unshift(collection.meta.total_count);
            active_user_chart.series[0].setData(points);
            active_user_chart.axes[0].setCategories(categories);
        },
    });
}
```

**Explanation:** UserLists have a corresponding month number on which they have to be sorted. They are stored in categories. Number of users in a list is the result. It is stored in points.

How do I tackle this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but you probably want to use a closure to capture the value and use that in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

```
var Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  // The Twitter Search API returns tweets under "results".
  parse: function(response) {
    response.results.forEach(function(result){
        result['myOwnId']=result.xyz+result.abc;
    });
    return response.results;
  }
});
```

Above code is untested and just explains of how you can add your own attributes to the collection.

In order to have your own sorting logic, you have to define your own `comparator` over the `collection`. From the docs

> A comparator can be defined as a sortBy (pass a function that takes a
>   single argument), as a sort (pass a comparator function that expects
>   two arguments), or as a string indicating the attribute to sort by.

A sample comparator could look like :

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
      // The Twitter Search API returns tweets under "results".
      sortBy: function(model) {
        return model.get('myOwnId');
      }
    });
```